# MYSQL Foreign Key, Cant create table (errno:150)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-150

I am trying to build the database and tables for my system. But I found that if I don't add the foreign key in the codes. There is no error. I've used many method try to make the codes works, but it still have error.

```
Create table if not exists users_details_one
(
    fname varchar(255),
    lname varchar(255),
    address varchar(255),
    users_email varchar(255),
    users_password varchar(255),
    department varchar(255)
 );

Create table if not exists users_one
(
    users_email varchar(255),
    users_password varchar(255) ,

    FOREIGN KEY (users_email) REFERENCES users_details_one(users_email),

    FOREIGN KEY (users_password) REFERENCES users_details_one(users_password)   
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your foreign key:
`FOREIGN KEY (users_password) REFERENCES users_details_one(users_spassword)` should be `FOREIGN KEY (users_password) REFERENCES users_details_one(users_password)`

and you also need indexes on `users_email` and `users_password` in table `users_details_one`, such as this:

```
Create table if not exists users_details_one
(
    fname varchar(255),
    lname varchar(255),
    address varchar(255),
    users_email varchar(255),
    users_password varchar(255),
    department varchar(255),
    index (users_email),
    index (users_password)
 );

Create table if not exists users_one
(
    users_email varchar(255),
    users_password varchar(255) ,

    FOREIGN KEY (users_email) REFERENCES users_details_one(users_email),

    FOREIGN KEY (users_password) REFERENCES users_details_one(users_password)   
);
```

it is not necessary for the index to be unique.

[from the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a column as a foreign key, those columns must be either primary keys aur must have a uniqueness constraint i.e. in your case the users_email and users_password of users_details_one must be unique or primary keys.

Comment: no. they do not need to be primary keys OR unique. they do need to be indexed however.